# Do understand some code using abstract class in php

Tags: php, abstract-class

I understand the concept of abstract class, but I saw a code in a book that I do not understand.

I will short the code and would like you help me to understand, I know what it does I just don't why is working.

Here I declared and abstract class DataObject and its contructor

```
abstract class DataObject {
    protected $data = array();

    public function __construct( $data ){
        foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
        {
            if( array_key_exists( $key, $this->data )) 
                $this->data[$key] = $value;
        }       
    }
}
```

Then I have this

```
class Member extends DataObject {
    protected $data = array(
                        "username" => "",
                        "password" => ""
    );

    public function getInfo(){
        echo "Usernarme: " . $this->data["username"] . " <br/>password: " . $this->data["password"];
    }
}
```

So when I do this

```
$m= new Member( array( 
                    "username" => "User",
                    "password" => "Some password" )
                );
$m->getInfo();
```

I get

Usernarme: User
password: Some password

To be more specific.

- Looks like since I did not create a constructor for the extended class is calling implicitly the father class, right?
- How the constructor works in a way that it is validating the data array according to the Member array values?, I mean if when I create the Object

$m= new Member( array( 
                    "username" => "User",
                    "password" => "Some password" )
                );

Change the key "username" for "usernames" it won't assign the value "User" for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent constructor:

```
if( array_key_exists( $key, $this->data )) 
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
```

This prevents it from creating new keys.  In the child class the keys "username" and "password" are defined, so those are the only keys that the constructor will allow to be written.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know that it prevents it, but how? when a create a new member is calling the parent constructor how is related with the son?

Comment: Since you instantiate the child, the child's version of `$data` is what is used.  However, since the parent's constructor is not overridden (i.e., no constructor is defined in the child) it is the one which is called when you create a new instance of the object.

Comment: when it said $this->data does it is talking about $data array's son? why?

Comment: Okay now i get it  the child's version of $data is what is used Thanks, i was confuse with the $data of the parent, but of course  I instantiate the child

Comment: Because you used `$m= new Member` and not `$m= new DataObject`; think of it like a painting.  I take a canvas and I paint blue squares in a checkerboard pattern.  Then I give the canvas to you, and you paint yellow squares over every other blue square, and some white squares at random.  When you show people the canvas, they will see only the blue squares you **didn't** cover, and otherwise they will see your yellow squares where you covered my blue ones.  In the same way, if you declare something with the same name, e.g. `$data`, it will overwrite its parent IF you instantiate the child.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like since I did not create a constructor for the extended class is calling implicitly the father class, right?

Not implicitly, but explictly. By "not creating a constructor" you didn't *override* the existing one.

> How the constructor works in a way that it is validating the data array according to the Member array values?, I mean if when I create the Object
>
> ```
> $m= new Member( array( "username" => "User", "password" => "Some password" ) );
> ```
>
> Change the key "username" for "usernames" it won't assign the value "User" for example.

Yes. Because in the parent class you define, that the value should only be set, if the key exists, the non-existing key "usernames" is silently omitted.

Comment: How does it get that relation, maybe is somehting that i missing but i do not see it

Comment: `class Member ` **`extends `** `DataObject` =)

Comment: The property `$data` gets overriden in the child class.